# Passing parameters from Android FragmentActivity to Fragment

Tags: android, parameters, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

When Im trying to pass a parameter from FragmentActivity to a Fragment it gives me null pointer exception in the getArguments() in the Fragment.

Here is my FragmentActivity Code

```
  public class IndexChartActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.index_chart);

            IndexFragmentActivity indexFragment =   
 (IndexFragmentActivity)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.index_fragment);
            indexFragment.newInstance("ASPI");

        }

    }
```

Here is the index_chart.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/header_fragment"
        android:name="com.lk.ignitionit.cse.util.HeaderFragmentActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/index_fragment"
        android:name="com.lk.ignitionit.cse.util.IndexFragmentActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:name="com.lk.ignitionit.cse.util.ChartFragmentActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and Here is the Fragment

```
public class IndexFragmentActivity extends Fragment {
    protected ImageView ivASPI;
    protected ImageView ivMPI;
    protected ImageView ivSP;
    protected TextView tvMain;
    protected TextView tvTop;
    protected TextView tvBottom;
    String response = null;
    String result = null;
    String []  resultArr = null;
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    String indexType = null;
    int layout;
    IndexFragmentActivity f = null;

    public  IndexFragmentActivity newInstance(String index) {
        f = new IndexFragmentActivity();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("indextype", index);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    public String getSelectedIndex() {
        return f.getArguments().getString("indextype");
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(getSelectedIndex().equals("ASPI")){
            layout = R.layout.aspi_header;
        }else if(getSelectedIndex().equals("MPI")){
            layout = R.layout.mpi_header;
        }else{
            layout = R.layout.sp_header;
        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, container, false);

        tvMain = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_main);
        tvTop = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_top);
        tvBottom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_bottom);


        new ServiceAccess().execute("");

        tvMain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                b.putString("type", "S&P SL20");
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, IndexChartActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);  

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

and Here is my ERROR

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.lk.ignitionit.cse.util.IndexFragmentActivity.getSelectedIndex(IndexFragmentActivity.java:69)
```

I referred lots of stackoverflow questions relevant to this and tried the sample code given http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html as well. But still no luck

Really appreciate any feed back on this as this seems to be a very basic issue which I cannot figure out..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Get rid of `Activity` from the names of all classes that do not inherit from `Activity`. For example, 
   `IndexFragmentActivity` is not an `Activity`.
2. In `onCreate()` of your actual activity, you are calling `findFragmentById()` to retrieve a fragment, then calling `newInstance()` on that fragment. However, the fragment will not exist the first time `onCreate()` is called, and you will fail here with a `NullPointerException`. Please correctly handle this case.
3. The method name `newInstance` in Java is most commonly associated with the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), where `newInstance()` is a `static` method used in place of a public constructor to create instances of some class. Your `newInstance()` method is not `static`. This will cause confusion for those who come after you to maintain the code.
4. You call `newInstance()` in `onCreate()`, create the new fragment instance, and then throw it away, which is a waste of time.

Hence, assuming that your original instance of your fragment (wherever it came from) does not have an arguments `Bundle` set, that would explain your `NullPointerException` in `getSelectedIndex()`.

> When Im trying to pass a parameter from FragmentActivity to a Fragment

To pass a parameter to a *newly created* fragment, using a `static` `newInstance()` method and the arguments `Bundle` to create the *new* fragment is perfectly reasonable.

To pass a parameter to a fragment that already exists, simply call some setter method on that fragment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guides. I'll do work and update the answers once I fixed the issue.